# Is there a way I can make a chrome extension that on press opens another application on the computer using their API

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, whatsapp

I have tried to find the ways on the internet and stack overflow but I wasn't able to find an answer. What I want is-

Eg. [whatsapp://open](http://whatsapp://open)- Opens the Whatsapp window.

I want to make an extension that performs the same thing i.e. open and be able to perform actions using the API of the external application.

Comment: Looks like you can't, see https://crbug.com/64100. There is a standard navigator.registerProtocolHandler though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by 'press' you mean navigation to an address?
Or is it a click on a button?

As of March 2020 you can't register to a protocol from an extension. You *can* however use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to come very close.

The process involves coding a standalone executable, called "native messaging host" in the docs (or multiple ones if you need to support multiple platforms). The extension *can* send messages to it and it can then open whichever windows and applications it desires.

Your extension can choose to send such message to the native messaging host based on events triggered by webNavigation events, webRequest events, or tabs.onChanged.  If you'd provide more details on the exact triggers you want and exact actions you want to take maybe we can help with more details.